# Notebook downloaded from web giving error message

Tags: compatibility

Just bought a copy of E. J. Mcinnerney's textbook *Computational Explorations in Magnetron Sputtering*. However, when I download and try Chap2.nb from:

http://www.computationalexplorations.com/mathematica-code.html

I get the following error in *Mathematica* 10.0.2:

> The specified setting for the option FontSize cannot be used.

Can someone point out what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `Medium`option from `BaseStyle` fixes your problem.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.